# Microsoft CRM 4.0 Announcement: How to customize recipients?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I want to send announcement only to certain recipient in my organization. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the [businessunitnewsarticle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb889160.aspx) entity, there is only a property called organizationid, to limit the target audience of the particular businessunitnewsarticle to the certain organization only.

Alternatively you can send an email activity if you only want to limit the recipients to a particular range.

Regards,

hadi